# Problem with convert median of a data matrix to vector or list

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a dataframe "prod_fm_wt_3 contain 12 integer column.
After I did a matrix transform

```
 `t <- t(prod_fm_wt_3)`
```

I did a median calculation

```
 w1 <- median(t[,1])
```

then if I use

```
print(w1)
```

it will show me 12 different numbers
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuTlY.png)

but when I want to put those 12 numbers into a data frame column

it show 12 same numbers,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lisfi.png)
How can I put the 12 number I print above to a column in data frame?

Comment: The Code I use for generate dataframe column is "test_frame$test=w1"

Comment: Hello @Kelly yisi Liu, Welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that other SO users can help you in the best way. Cheers.